# Regarding regex implementation

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to implement 2 regex for the below requirements.

1. **Legal Characters:** A-Z, a-z, 0-9, hyphen, apostrophe and single space.

   **Illegal Character:** leading space, trailing space, adjacent spaces, and other symbols. Length: min 1 max 35

For this I tried implementing the regex as follows `"^[ A-Za-z0-9'-]*$"`. I failed to implement the trailing space, adjacent spaces and for the min and max length.

2. **Legal Characters:** printable characters from "#x21;" to "#x7E;" and single space.

**Illegal Character:** leading space, trailing space, adjacent spaces. Length: min 1 max 35

For this I tried, `"^(?> *)[\x21-\x7F]+$"`. I am not getting how to implement trailing space, adjacent spaces and for the min and max length.

Thanks.

Comment: This one for the first requirement?: [`^(?!\s)(?!.*\s\s)[ A-Za-z0-9'-]*(?<!\s)$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f!%5cs)(%3f!.*%5cs%5cs)%5b+A-Za-z0-9%27-%5d*(%3f%3c!%5cs)%24&i=Hello+World)

Comment: Maybe its a litte bit faster if you replace `(?!.*\s\s)[ A-Za-z0-9'-]*` with [`(\s(?!\s)|[A-Za-z0-9'-])*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f!%5cs)(%5cs(%3f!%5cs)%7c%5bA-Za-z0-9%27-%5d)*(%3f%3c!%5cs)%24&i=Hello+World). I didn't test performance of both.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. But I think it doesn't validate the length.

Comment: Ups... Yes... Replace `*` with [`{1,35}`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f!%5cs)(%5cs(%3f!%5cs)%7c%5bA-Za-z0-9%27-%5d)%7b1%2c35%7d(%3f%3c!%5cs)%24&i=Hello+World).

Comment: I tried the variation of what you have given for the second one. "^(?!\s)(?!.*\s\s)[\x20-\x7F]{1,35}(?<!\s)$"

Comment: Till now yes, still doing some testing.... Thanks. Do you feel it wont?

Comment: No but I didn't use the `\xAA` syntax before and that's why I can't say anything about it. That's also why I don't added my comment as answer because it only solves the first problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the first you can use this:

```
^(?=^.{1,35}$)(?!\s)(?!.*\s\s)[ A-Za-z0-9'-]*(?<!\s)$
```

And for the second one just change the middle class from `[ A-Za-z0-9'-]` to `[ \x21-\x7E]`:

```
^(?=^.{1,35}$)(?!\s)(?!.*\s\s)[ \x21-\x7E]*(?<!\s)$
```